# show the div in the center of the bottom of the selected td

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table that has some inputs..

when the user presses the enter key in an input, I want to put the div below of the selected input (in the center).

for examples:

[image]

this is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/Ht6Ym/2371/

and this is the html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></input></td>
        <td><input type="text"></input></td>
        <td>fshsfh</td>
        <td>347</td>
        <td><input type="text"></input></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id = "myDiv" class="callout bottom" style="position:absolute;display:none;">sgsf f shfs hfs hfsh </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/kRHLH/3/**

It's not exactly in the center of each.  I'm working on tweaking that now.  But I think this looks fine.  The red box starts at the beginning of each input.  But I'll work on getting it in the middle.  Basically have to get the width of the input and do a bit more math.

This is just the JavaScript, see fiddle for everything cause I altered your CSS a little.

```
$('input').live('keypress', function (event) {
    if (event.which == '13') {
        d = document.getElementById('myDiv');
        d.style.display = "";
        elOffsetX = $(this).offset().left;
        elOffsetY = $(this).offset().top;
        d.style.left = elOffsetX+'px';
        d.style.top = elOffsetY+'px';
    }
});
```

Comment: To get it in the exact center of the field do like @PatrickEvans shows.  But I altered his fiddle a bit so that the red box doesn't appear so far below the fields.  And this fiddle shows how it looks on fields that are different widths, so you can verify it really is calculating correctly: **http://jsfiddle.net/NNGSX/1/**

Comment: yea was going to move it right under but i thought heck he can do that part of the work :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xt8k8/2/)

```
$("#myDiv").css("left",$(this).offset().left);
```

Add this code after the line where you remove the display:none from the div.

This code will not center the div to the input, but to the left.  In order to center it you need to determine first the width of both (the div and the input) and then add it after the '.left'

Comment: check your fiddle, it doesn't seem to run for me.  enter key does nothing.

Comment: Fiddle fixed. I set the JQuery version incorrectly by accident.

Answer (score 1):

To center a element based on another element,

1. get the width and left values of the element you are wanting to center on
2. then get the width of the element you want to center
3. then half both widths
4. minus the centered on elements half width from the centering elements half width
5. add this new value to the left of the center on element

So:

```
$('input').on("keypress",function(e){
    if(e.which=="13"){
      //Gets the bounding rectangle of the element, gives left,top,right,bottom,width,height
      var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
      var l = rect.left;
      var b = rect.bottom;
      var iw = rect.width;
      var dw = $("#myDiv").outerWidth();
      $("#myDiv").css("left",(l+((iw/2)-(dw/2)))+"px");
      $("#myDiv").css("top",b+"px");
      $("#myDiv").show();
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ht6Ym/2375/)